# Sonarqube - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

```
SonarQube Environment:-
SonarQube Version - 6.7.7 LTS
sonar-cxx-plugin version -1.2.2.1653.jar
sonar-scanner version -3.0.3.778
Execution through Jenkins SonarQube Scanner section.

Jenkins SonarQube Analysis properties consists of below additionally 
sonar.skipPackageDesign=true
sonar.skipDesign=true
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx1280m
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx1280m

JVM Options-Xmx10240m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms10240m
```

SonarQube execution completed successfully, However it is hanging and after sometime exists with below errors.

```
15:25:10 15:29:09.683 WARN: Preprocessor: 159 include directive error(s). This is only relevant if parser creates syntax errors. The preprocessor searches for include files in the with 'sonar.cxx.includeDirectories' defined directories and order.
15:25:10 15:29:09.683 WARN: Source code parser: 1617 syntax error(s) detected. Syntax errors could cause invalid software metric values. Root cause are typically missing includes, missing macros or compiler specific extensions.
15:25:10 15:29:09.686 INFO: Task total time: 7.269 s
15:25:10 15:29:09.819 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:25:10 15:29:09.819 INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
15:25:10 15:29:09.819 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:25:10 15:29:09.819 INFO: Total time: 8.606s
15:25:10 15:29:09.908 INFO: Final Memory: 79M/9813M
15:25:10 15:29:09.908 DEBUG: Connection manager is shutting down
15:25:10 15:29:09.908 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:25:10 15:29:09.908 DEBUG: Connection manager shut down
15:31:27 FATAL: Remote call on SonarQube_Project_TLS_Modem failed
15:31:27 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
15:31:27 Caused: java.io.IOException: Remote call on SonarQube_Project_TLS_Modem failed
15:31:27  at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:963)
15:31:27  at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1070)
15:31:27  at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1059)
15:31:27  at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1893)
15:31:27  at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1877)
15:31:27  at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1862)
15:31:27  at hudson.plugins.sonar.utils.SonarUtils.extractReportTask(SonarUtils.java:89)
15:31:27  at hudson.plugins.sonar.utils.SonarUtils.addBuildInfoTo(SonarUtils.java:118)
15:31:27  at hudson.plugins.sonar.utils.SonarUtils.addBuildInfoTo(SonarUtils.java:134)
15:31:27  at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerBuilder.perform(SonarRunnerBuilder.java:301)
15:31:27  at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerBuilder.perform(SonarRunnerBuilder.java:247)
15:31:27  at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
15:31:27  at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
15:31:27  at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
15:31:27  at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
15:31:27  at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
15:31:27  at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1818)
15:31:27  at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
15:31:27  at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
15:31:27  at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Sonarqube server `sonar.log` doesn't have any errors. But Error message from `ce.log` Log file as follows

```
15:35:26 Caused: java.io.IOException: Remote call on SonarQube_Project_TLS_Modem failed
15:35:26     at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:963)
```

On Server `sonar.properties` have below configurations for `CE,WEB & Elastic Search`

```
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx4G -Xms4G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx4G -Xms4G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx4G -Xms4G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Since the execution completed successfully, we can able to view the report on SonarQube Dashboard without any problem. But each run through Jenkins hangs and after-some time fails with above error.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.

We had a symbolic link to "." setup as part of the build, i think that was causing sonar to find a infinite amount of report files.

I removed the symlink before sonar and all was good.

Comment: Hi Lance, Okay thanks for important point, i will check this.